# Install Location changer Batch

Tags: batch-file

I can't figure this out, I didn't really know how to formulate the question, I hope this is good enough
I am working on this as a experiment.
I get the message "The system cannot find the path specified" when I purposely insert a invalid directory.

```
@echo off
set /a test=0
title Color changer
if exist "Settings/files.bat" (
call Settings/files.bat
) else (
mkdir Settings
echo set savloc=%cd%>Settings\files.bat
call Settings\files.bat
)
if exist "%savloc%\color.bat" (
call "%savloc%\color.bat"
) else (
color 0f
)
set menu=2
goto menu

:menu
cls
echo color : change color
echo cd : change direction
set /p menu=
if "%menu%" == "color" goto setcolor
if "%menu%" == "cd" goto changedir
else goto menu

:changedir
cls
set test=0
echo (current location: %savloc%)
echo What do you want your new location to be?
set /p dir=#
echo set test=1 > "%dir%\testfile.bat"
call "%dir%\testfile.bat"

If EXIST "%dir%\testfile.bat" (
echo Valid Location! (current location: %dir%)
pause >nul
echo set savloc=%dir%> Settings\files.bat
call Settings\files.bat
del "%dir%\testfile.bat"
goto menu
)
iF NOT EXIST "%dir%\testfile.bat" (
echo Invalid Location, Please redo This step. (reset location to: %cd%)
pause >nul
echo set savloc=%cd%> Settings\files.bat
call Settings\files.bat
del "%dir%\testfile.bat"
goto menu
)

goto menu

:setcolor
cls
echo What do you want the color to be?
echo.
set /p clr=#
color %clr%
echo color %clr%>"%savloc%\color.bat"
goto menu
```

I have tried using the "test" variable, it being saved to that directory and then read, instead of:

```
 If EXIST "%dir%\testfile.bat" (
```

and

```
 If NOT EXIST "%dir%\testfile.bat" (
```

but that also didn't work.

I really hope someone can help me.

Update:
Now I changed the statement to:

```
if exist "%dir%" (
    echo Valid Location! (current location: %dir%)
    pause >nul
    echo set savloc=%dir%> Settings\files.bat
    call Settings\files.bat
    goto menu
) else (
    echo Invalid Location, Please redo This step. (reset location to: %cd%)
    pause >nul
    echo set savloc=%cd%> Settings\files.bat
    call Settings\files.bat
    goto menu
)

goto menu
```

But now when the directory is invalid, it just echoes it into settings\files.bat
and it doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing into `%dir%\testfile.bat` *before* testing the directory.

When directory is invalid, redirection cannot work and you get the error message.

check *directory* existence first. Example of fix:

```
set /p dir=#

If NOT EXIST "%dir% ( echo "%dir% does not exist
goto menu
)

rem now echo has a chance to work
echo set test=1> "%dir%\testfile.bat"
call "%dir%\testfile.bat"
```

Comment: I did that, it still doesn't really work, I updated the question.
I hope you can help.

Thanks that you replied so quickly.